# Do the keys of App Engine datastore entities stay constant over time?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, primary-key

Can we expect the datastore key for an entity to stay unchanged over the course of time or is their encoding likely to change as Google updates the App Engine versions? I am asking this because I am planning to use datastore entity key as the unique identifier for records in my Android app.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While they will never change in the same appspot application (by definition of "a key uniquely identifies an entity") BUT they could change in the future if Google deprecates the HDR datastore for something else.

For example, when they deprecated the previous datastore (master/slave), you had to migrate to another appspot (with a different app url). All keys changed. The migration tool handled natively stored key references and the developer had to take care of the serialized ones.

see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration section "Migrating Serialized Datastore Keys" for an official doc that shows it happened in the last migration.

Note this is a one-in-5-years situation but something to be aware.

Comment: But the datastore keys for existing entities didn't change, it's just that you had to create entirely new ones in the new datastore. A key for an entity itself will never change.

Comment: thats what I said in the first paragraph :)  but you were forced to move the app to another app, effectively "changing" the ids from the point of view of an external application (android app)